# Call to mysql_insert_id gives warning

Tags: php, mysql, warnings, mysql-insert-id

Hi I'm receiving this warning when trying to retrieve the insert id

> Warning: mysql_insert_id(): supplied
>   argument is not a valid MySQL-Link
>   resource

in

```
mysql_query($importword); 
$word_id = mysql_insert_id($importword);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you get the id and that id you want to insert just write
mysql_insert_id(); after your query.

Answer (score 3):

`$importword` is the query that you are executing using `msql_query`.

Next you are passing the *query* to `mysql_insert_id` which is incorrect. [**mysql_insert_id**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) takes the link identifier which is optional.

If you are not having multiple connections open, just don't pass anything:

```
mysql_query($importword); 
// do some error checking.

$word_id = mysql_insert_id();
```

so that it uses the last link opened by `mysql_connect`

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to pass the connection, or leave it empty to use the last one opened.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_insert_id take the resource identifier not the query

either pass resource or leave blank

```
$word_id = mysql_insert_id();
```